# how to parse the below type json response?

Tags: android, json

Hi i am completely new to android.please suggest me how to parse the below jsonresposne and get the values.any help please suggest me.i don't know how to parse because it contains both square bracket and curly bracket.

```
 `[  
   {  
      "bus_schedule":[  
         {  
            "bus_route":[  
               {  
                  "serviceDate":"2016-12-31",
                  "amenities":" VB King Size Semi Sleeper (2 plus 1) selected WIFI,Water,Bottle,Blankets,Snacks,Movie,Food,Emergency exit, Fire Extinguisher,Bus Hostess,CCTV,Emergency Contact Number",
                  "startCityName":"Coimbatore",
                  "departureTime":"21:00:00",
                  "fare":"499",
                  "endCityName":"Kanyakumari",
                  "arrivalTime":"06:00:00",
                  "operatorName":"RUN TO WIN",
                  "bus_id":"17",
                  "journeyHours":"9",
                  "available_seat":25,
                  "total_seats":34,
                  "seat_type":"semi sleeper"
               }
            ],"boardingPoint":[  
               {  
                  "boardingPointName":"Thudiyalur",
                  "boardingPointContact":"8883088820",
                  "boardingPointTime":"21:25:00",
                  "boardingPointId":"316",
                  "BusId":"17"
               },`

            my code is 
                  `protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                     HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
                   ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            try {
                response= mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                return  null;
            }
            Log.i("routes",""+response);
            jsonstr=response;

          if(jsonstr!= null){
              try{
                  /*JSONArray jsonary=new JSONArray(jsonstr);
                  JSONArray bus_scheduleee=jsonary.getJSONArray("bus_schedule");*/
                   JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
                  JSONArray bus_schedule = jsonObj.getJSONArray("bus_schedule");
                  JSONArray bus_route = jsonObj.getJSONArray("bus_route");
                  for (int i = 0; i < bus_route.length(); i++) {
                      JSONObject c = bus_route.getJSONObject(i);
                      String journeydatefromjson=c.getString("serviceDate");
                      String busname=c.getString("amenities");
                      String fromplace_json=c.getString("startCityName");
                      String departtimejson=c.getString("departureTime");
                      String farefromjson=c.getString("fare");
                      String endCityNamejson=c.getString("endCityName");
                      String arrivalTimejson=c.getString("arrivalTime");
                      String operatorNamejson=c.getString("operatorName");
                      String bus_idjson=c.getString("bus_id");
                      String journeyHoursjson=c.getString("journeyHours");
                      String available_seatjson=c.getString("available_seat");
                      String total_seatsjson=c.getString("total_seats");
                      String seat_typejson=c.getString("journeyHours");

                     Log.d("busdetails",""+journeydatefromjson+busname);
                  }

              } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
            return null;
        }`
```

Comment: Your description ("both square brackets and curly brackets") suggests you might not understand what JSON is.  If you would be able to explain what square and curly brackets mean in JSON, that's good, carry on.  If not, you should learn it before you proceed or you're just going to run into problems every time you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try use Gson lib for parse it.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}
```

You can generation pojo for parse json. (For example on this site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org)

For parse use this.

```
T t = new Gson().fromJson(serverResponse.getResponse(), type);
```

Where 'T' is your response data, and 'type' it pojo from site.

If your type is entity use Type type = Entity.class;
If your type is list of entities use

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<WadadayFull>>() {
            }.getType())
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
try {
            JSONArray array1 = new JSONArray(str);
            for (int i=0;i<array1.length();i++){
                JSONObject obj1 = array1.getJSONObject(i) ;
                JSONArray array2 = obj1.getJSONArray("bus_schedule");
                for (int j=0;j<array2.length();j++){
                    JSONObject obj2 = array2.getJSONObject(j);
                    JSONArray array3 = obj2.getJSONArray("bus_route");
                    ArrayList<Example1> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int k=0;k<array3.length();k++) {
                        JSONObject obj3 = array3.getJSONObject(k);

                        String s1 = obj3.getString("serviceDate");
                        String s2 = obj3.getString("amenities");
                        String s3 = obj3.getString("startCityName");
                        String s4 = obj3.getString("departureTime");
                        String s5 = obj3.getString("fare");
                        String s6 = obj3.getString("endCityName");
                        String s7 = obj3.getString("arrivalTime");
                        String s8 = obj3.getString("operatorName");
                        String s9 = obj3.getString("bus_id");
                        String s10 = obj3.getString("journeyHours");
                        String s11 = obj3.getString("available_seat");
                        String s12 = obj3.getString("total_seats");
                        String s13 = obj3.getString("seat_type");

                        Example1 ex1 = new Example1();
                        ex1.setServiceDate(s1);
                        ex1.setAmenities(s2);
                        ex1.setStartCityName(s3);

                        list.add(ex1);
                        Log.e("response", list.toString());


                    }

                    JSONArray array4 = obj2.getJSONArray("boardingPoint");
                    ArrayList<Example2> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int l = 0; l < array4.length(); l++) {
                        JSONObject obj4 = array4.getJSONObject(l);

                        String s14 = obj4.getString("boardingPointName");
                        String s15 = obj4.getString("boardingPointContact");
                        String s16 = obj4.getString("boardingPointTime");
                        String s17 = obj4.getString("boardingPointId");
                        String s18 = obj4.getString("BusId");
                        Example2 ex2 = new Example2();
                        ex2.setBoardingPointName(s14);
                        ex2.setBoardingPointContact(s15);
                        list2.add(ex2);
                        Log.e("response", list2.toString());
                    }

                }

            }

            Log.e("response",array1.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```